# Different ways to arrange a set of numbers, so X can be seen from the left and Y can be seen from the right

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, computer-science, contest-math

Given an set of unique integers of length N. What are number of different ways you can rearrange the array so that, you can only see X numbers of integers from the left and Y numbers of integers from the right, with the restriction being that the biggr integer in the set blocks the smaller integers. So if you had say [10,40,60,20], you would see 3 from the left and 2 from the right.

Example:

Given: N = 3, X = 2, Y = 2 Output: 2

Given: N = 6, X = 1, Y = 2 Output: 24

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Well, my approach is to use the biggest integer in the set, and iterate through all the possible position it can be in. The only difficulty is probability to find the different permutation of the positioning of other integers once I fixed the biggest integer at a certain position

Comment: Just clarifying that by "unique" you mean "distinct", yes?

Comment: Yes, no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a tractable recurrence if, instead of considering where the largest number is, you look at the smallest number.

The indexing will seem strange here, but bear with me. Let $f(n,l,r)$ denote the number of permutations of $\{0,\ldots,n\}$ where $l+1$ elements are visible from the left and $r+1$ are visible from the right.  Clearly $f(n,l,r)=0$ if either $l$ or $r$ is negative, since at least one element (the largest) is visible on each side.  We have $f(0,l,r)=[l=r=0]$. Also, the only way the smallest element is visible is if it is at one end, so we get the recurrence
$$f(n,l,r)=f(n-1,l-1,r)+f(n-1,l,r-1)+(n-1)f(n-1,l,r)$$
for $n>1$.

It's not hard to show inductively that 
$$f(n,l,r)=\binom{l+r}{r}\,|S_n^{(l+r)}|$$
where $S_n^{(k)}$ denotes the Stirling number of the first kind. (There's probably a simple direct argument but I haven't had time to think about that.)

In particular, the two given examples are $\binom21\,|S_2^{(2)}|=2$ and $\binom10\,|S_5^{(1)}|=24$.